# Barcode scanning into web browser issue

Tags: .net, google-chrome, bluetooth, barcode, scanning

We just came across an issue where scanning a bar code into a web browser would have hugely inconsistent results, mainly by switching the last two digits around. E.g. scanning 64571 would return 64517 around 20% of the time. This happened mainly on Chrome and IE (others were untested).

There were loads of variables at play: it was a Bluetooth scanner with varying distances between the scanner and the laptop.

Answer (score 2):

After testing every thing we could think of with hardware, it turns out this only happened on a browser. On Notepad, we got perfect results. We tried new scanners, new laptops, connecting the scanner with a cable, larger bar codes, new bar code standard.

In the end the answer seems quite simple. We changed the input "text mode" of the text box to password, and the scanning has been 100% since. It may have something to do with Auto Complete, we're not sure, but I thought it was worth a post in case anyone else came across the issue.

Comment: What tool did you use to implement this? I am trying to add a scan gun scanner to a web application.

Comment: Initial research of implementation found Web Bluetooth API but is not supported on iOS Safari.